# Workflow association to Doc library on new item and modify

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm a SharePoint beginner and using 2010.

I've associated a workflow for a document library which gets triggered on adding new document.

Also one more Workflow to get triggered when the document's properties are modified to the same document library. However, when I add new document, I see both the workflows are getting executed.

Also later if I change the document's properties, the latter workflow is not getting triggered again.

Please suggest some approach to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setting your workflow like this: the first workflow will be triggered when item is added, and the second workflow will be triggered when item is changed. You can use SP designer to change that. See the attachment[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response however it did not solve my problem. "When I add new document, I see both the workflows are getting executed."